# Access local files via a web server on another comupter

Tags: php, linux, ssh, file-sharing

I have LAMP server and a recordings server with small audio files. I would like to be able to access the audio files and embed them on a web page on the LAMP server. I do not want to create a share on the recordings server cause there are to many servers I need to do this to. I was thinking of the ssh2_sftp command in php but once I get the file via ssh2-sftp how can I embed that in the page? Also the audio files are available via HTTP but prefer not to do it that way the recordings server can be accessed via the local network.

UPDATE 7/15/2013

Ok I have figured out how to get access to the file on the local recordings server. But now I am having trouble embedding this the audio file in the page so the user can listen to it.

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('IP', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/$path/$filename", 'r');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of using ssh2_sftp would work (or any type of copy command, for that matter - even just scp), to copy the files from the remote recordings server to the lamp server.  Just copy the files to a web-accessible directory on the LAMP server, then your web pages can link to these files via their respective URL's.  The whole thing (including the copy) can be done on the fly in PHP.

Comment: There will be 1000s of audio files on the per recordings server constantly changing. There will 100s of new audio files every couple of minutes. Only 1- 3 audio files will listened at once per recording server. So I would rather keep the files on the recordings server then only create a temp copy on the web server as they are asked for.

Comment: Yes.  that's exactly why I think the idea of copying only the files that are needed on the LAMP server - on the fly (i.e. in the PHP script) - is the way to go.  Then, you can setup a cron job on the LAMP server to delete the files that are no longer needed at the end of each day.